# Обращение к дочернему элементу в HTML через Js

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, frontend

```
<div class="store__item active" id="205">
            <img src="assets/img/store/test.jpg" alt="" class="store__img">
            <div class="store__info">
                <span class="store__title">Belaz</span></br>
                <span class="store__suptitle">+32 click</span>
            </div>
            <div class="store__addinfo">
                <span class="store__price" id="2205">6400</span></br>
                <span class="store__performance" id="1205">+0</span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Могу ли я используя id обратиться к .store__title через document.querySelector / document.getElementById или что то подобное, чтобы не приписывать каждому элементу свой id или оригинальный класс, а чтобы я мог давать id сразу блоку с элементами и взаимодействовать через него?

Answer (score 1):

> Могу ли

Можешь

```js
let html = document.getElementById('205').querySelector('.store__info').innerHTML;

console.log(html);
```

```html
<div class="store__item active" id="205">
  <img src="assets/img/store/test.jpg" alt="" class="store__img">
  <div class="store__info">
    <span class="store__title">Belaz</span></br>
    <span class="store__suptitle">+32 click</span>
  </div>
  <div class="store__addinfo">
    <span class="store__price" id="2205">6400</span></br>
    <span class="store__performance" id="1205">+0</span>
  </div>
</div>
```